# Where to place CRUD functionality in Entity Framework DB First .Net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently learning how to use the Entity Framework with DB first functionaility.

I am developing an ASP.Net Webforms application.

I am a little confused as to where to implement my CRUD functionality.

For example, I have a "Member" table with various fields.

I have a webforms page which lists my members in a gridview.  I have a modal popup form where I can edit and update these member records.

Should I put my CRUD in the codebehind of my page or should I seperate this by having a Members Controller class whhich has an update function, called from my webform?

Also, if I have a function which updates all of the Member's attributes, what should I do if I wanted to update a single value, for example?

Should I code my update method in the controller class to accept "null" values and update only the fields which are not supplied as null in the arguments?

Apologies if I have made this sound more confusing than it should be.

Thank you in advance,

Grant.

Comment: You could add a "Repository" project where you create different classes the implements the CRUD operation for your model classes. So for example if you have a Member class you can add a MemberDB class in the repository project. Here you keep all the methods that work with the database. Nothing prevents you to add a UpdateAll and UpdateField method for each value you need to update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers to this question are going to depend on who you ask, it's quite opinion based. Personally, I like to create an API project for all the collections, which has the standard REST actions:

```
| Action | Route        | Description
|--------|--------------|------------------------------------------------------------
| GET    | api/Foo      | Lists all 'Foo's. May allow filters, ordering, and paging.
| POST   | api/Foo      | Adds a 'Foo' to the collection, and returns the id.
| GET    | api/Foo/{id} | Gets a 'Foo' from the collection by id.
| PUT    | api/Foo/{id} | Updates a 'Foo' with the given value.
| PATCH  | api/Foo/{id} | Updates specific fields in a 'Foo' with the given values.
| DELETE | api/Foo/{id} | Removes a 'Foo' from the collection by id.
```

The logic for each action is implemented in the controller for that collection. Then I make another project, which allows me to access the REST api through a C# client, e.g.

```
public class FooStore
{
    public IList<Foo> List()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public int Add(Foo foo)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Update(int id, Foo foo)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Update(int id, IDictionary<string, object> fields)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Remove(int id)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In the project that is actually presenting the data, I include and use the C# client where necessary.

This may seem a bit overkill for a small project, but it is a nice convention to follow, and results in a very logical coupling between the projects. It allows you to update the UI and the API separately, so existing clients don't break. It also allows you to create UIs for multiple platforms, e.g. a native android app, an iOS app, and a windows forms application, which all use the same API.

Comment: Hi Andrew. Many thanks for the answer.  This seems like the way to go.

I am currently using an addon called DevExpress which makes use of Entity Framework datasources to create gridviews and other controls on my webforms project.

If I switch to this kind of structure, I'm not sure if I will be able to use this set of controls successfully.

So I'm understanding you correctly, you have:

API Project > Project Accessing API > Web Forms Project

Lots of my controls in my webform project such as gridviews are generated from data accessed through EF.  Will this be possible still?

Comment: You're welcome, @GrantS. I can't see documentation for DevExpress (perhaps I have to pay first), but most UI frameworks allow you to provide custom data sources. For example, with the standard forms GridView, you can subclass [DataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter?view=netframework-4.7.2) and have it use a `FooStore`

Answer (score 0):

> I am currently learning how to use the Entity Framework with DB first
>   functionaility.

As you are learning I bet you are going to write a small - medium app (not too big), so my advise would be to **keep the CRUD code in the code behind**.

If you were using **EF DB Frist with MVC**, and you [scaffolded the controller and views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/generating-views), you will see that **the CRUD operations are generated in the Controller** (it *could be seen* as the .aspx.cs code behind), not in the Views (those *could be seen as the .aspx*) and not in the model's clases.

So to keep the CRUD operations in the code behind is OK... *if* you are not planning to build a solution that will work on web and needs to be connected to mobile devices using web services (maybe REST); in that case [Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50476830/4773983) is the way to go.

Some people could advise you to use the *some kind of Repository pattern*, **that would be overkill** for small apps, and **it will add complexity** *now* that you are learning. Also [Entity Framework implements already a Repository Pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/220126/185491).